# Intel Turbo Boost does not work with the "Powersave" CPU Governor

Tags: 18.04, power-management, performance, intel, cpu

Intel Turbo Boost does not kick-in with the "Powersave" governor.

It does on the "Performance" governor, but it locks the frequency at turbo boost even when the CPU is idle.

**"Performance" Governor:**

- CPU frequency locked at Turbo Boost mode always (3.2Ghz).
- Thus making the CPU run hot for no reason.

**"Powersave" Governor:**

- CPU frequency is 800Mhz on Idle, which is ideal, but it maxes out at 2.6Ghz on 100% usage. Which means Intel Turbo Boost is never activated.

**What I would like to achieve:**

I want that Intel Turbo Boost kicks in when using the "Powersave" Governor, so I can have low frequencies on Idle and maximum performance on near 100% CPU usage. I don't want to lock my governor to "Performance" mode because I like the low frequency on idles that the "powersave" gives me.

**Details:**

- **CPU:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
- **Max frequency with Turbo Boost:** 3.20Ghz
- **OS:** Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- **Kernel:** 5.3.0-46-generic

frequency-info while doing a stress test with "powersave" governor:

```
[lucas:~/local/box] bfdd3ffb(+1/-1)* ± cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.50 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.50 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 2.90 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

and with the "performance" governor:

```
θ78° [lucas:~/local/box] bfdd3ffb(+1/-1)* ± cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.50 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.50 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 3.32 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

With both governors, turbo boost is active and `min_perf_pct` and `max_perf_pct` are the same:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
0
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct
22
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct
100
```